# What does "coll" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm learning Czech language, and in the book that I'm learning from, there's a translation from Czech to English. There's one word that came in between which is the word "coll". It's not in Czech so I think that it's an English word. Any help?

> Ano. Yes. *coll.* Jo. Yeah.
> Ne. No.

[Image of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbpNE.jpg)

Comment: None of that makes sense.

Comment: Probably an abbreviation of *colloquial* (*yeah* is a colloquial way of saying "yes" in English)

Comment: @Juhasz I think you're right, I  also think that the book is saying that "ano" is the more formal term of assent and can be translated as "yes" but that "jo" is the informal or colloquial term of assent and can be translated as "yeah". If I'm right then "jo" might also be translated as "OK".

Comment: [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coll.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coll.)

Comment: It's definitely "colloquial" but wow, what an odd way to place that in a textbook, especially for an Intro course. Very awk.

Comment: If the book is any good, the abbreviation "coll." will be explained somewhere as "colloquial". Have you checked the book for a list of abbreviations?

Comment: @ Anton yes I have checked... And it's not mentioned. Anyway, the question was answered and I got the help that I needed....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ano = Yes

Jo = Yeah (**coll**oquial words in both languages)

Ne = No

[image: Google translate shows that Czech's 'ano', 'jo', 'ne' respectively translate into 'yes', 'yeah', 'no']

Comment: This needs unpacking for readers.

Comment: @Araucaria - I'm not sure what you mean. Do I have to unpack "coll" from "colloquial" even though it is emphasised in bold?